# ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG broadcast delay

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, headset

I have my own `BroadcastReceiver` instance for `Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` action. There is about 1-2 seconds delay between actual physical unplugging a headset and a moment when my `BroadcastReceiver` is notified about that.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY - 1);
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // my code here
  }
}, filter);
```

Any ideas how to decrease the delay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Handling `AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY` broadcast did the trick :) Its intent is broadcast directly after headset is unplugged without any delay.

Comment: Hehe, I find it great that the very answer (which I'm not saying is wrong) that told you no, led to your little work around. Congratz!

Answer (score 3):

You are out of luck.

The delay is hardcoded in the framework, look in

```
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/HeadsetObserver.java
```

The delay is 1000 ms, due to the risk of having garbage in the audio pipeline.