# Headset control in Android

Tags: android, headset

In my music player program, I want to pause the music when extracting the headset by monitoring the headset broadcast. But when the headset is extracted, the music still plays about 0.5s and then pauses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ACTION\_HEADSET\_PLUG broadcast delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124368/action-headset-plug-broadcast-delay)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

> Handling AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY broadcast did the
>   trick :) Its intent is broadcast directly after headset is unplugged
>   without any delay.

I found this reciept [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4267213/1658267)